# Bash error reports

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Ok, I can get this to run and put the file on the remote server. However when it does run, I want it to echo a Transfer failed, Transfer OK, Zero bytes in file and No such file or directory. It just runs down the code and sends an email of the last entry which is no such file or directory when clearly the file transferred to the server. What am I doing wrong ??
Thx in advance, I thank you.

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST=10.10.1.2
USER='test'
RECIP="user@somemail.com"
cd /home/test
FILE=ARG$(date '+%Y%m%d').txt
BYTES=`stat -c%s $FILE`
CONNECTION=`netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED | awk '{print $5}' | awk -F: '{print $1}' |   sort | uniq -c | awk '{printf("%s\t%s\t",$2,$1) ; for (i = 0; i < $1; i++)    {printf("*")}; print ""}'`
RUN_AS=`whoami`
RESULT=`sftp $USER@$HOST <<EOF
FILE=ARG$(date '+%Y%m%d').txt
cd /998979/DES
if [ -e $FILE ]; then
put $FILE
EOF`

echo $CONNECTION "Connection to network is established."

ls | xargs wc -wl for file in *; echo $FILE done  
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "$RESULT" "Transfer of file failed. `date`"
SBJ="Transfer of file failed `date`"
fi
echo "$RESULT" "Transfer OK"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
SBJ="Transfer OK. `date`"
echo "$RESULT" "Transfer OK"
fi
if \[ ! -s ${FILE} \]; then
echo "File: ${FILE} is not present or a ZERO byte file"
SBJ="Failed to upload. Zero bytes in file. `date`" # zero bytes sent
fi
if [ -a $FILE ]; then
echo "$RESULT" "No such file or directory"
SBJ="No such file or directory. `date`"
fi

BODY="Process Report....... 

SRC SERVER:`hostname` 
DST SEVER: TESTSERVER
SCRIPT: /usr/local/bin/put.sh
RUN AS: "$RUN_AS" 

RESULT: "$RESULT" "$FILE"

CONNECTION: "$CONNECTION" 

FILENAME: "$FILE" 

BYTES: "$BYTES" 
DATE/TIME: `date`"

echo "$BODY" | mail -s "$SBJ" "$RECIP"
```

Comment: Hmm what exactly are you seeing now? `ls | xargs wc -wl for file in *; echo $FILE done` looks strange

Answer (score 2):

You can use `/bin/sh -xv yourshellscript.sh` to understand what is happening.

And you could log important messages to the system log using [logger](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_logger.htm)

Comment: The above just lists the files in the folder when the script runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
count=$?

if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then 
 echo "$RESULT" "Transfer of file failed. 
 `date`" SBJ="Transfer of file failed `date`" 
else 
 echo "$RESULT" "Transfer OK" 
fi
```

Assign the result to a variable, Also, try to use exit when you don't need to do more processing.

Comment: Tried the above, still no dice.

Comment: I can get it to produce the "error" no such file or directory and zero bytes in file. I just ran the script again and it came up "no such file or directory" when clearly I saw the FTP go over 100% Im so confused.